# how can we count or compare strings?

Tags: c++11

i want it to read 1 string at a time and count how many time a string appears after the comma like if A appear there is count += 1  and if B appears there a seperate count+= 1   and then do the same thing to another string and if it appear twices more than the first string than save it

Ex:

```
string num1 = "A, B , C, AB, AC"
string num2 = "A, B, C , AB, A, C, AC, AB"
istringstream uc(num2);
string num3
while(getline(uc,num3,',')) //get part of the string after you see ','
{


}
```

result: since they appear twice

```
C, AB , A
```

Comment: You may want to try writing the complete code first, then post a more specific question, if you still need help.

Comment: i'm not sure how i can make seperate counts for each different strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd create a function that counts the number of occurrences of each word in the string. I'd probably store that information in a `std::map`, since that's fairly convenient.

Then, I'd simply iterate through the counts for `num2`, and if it's greater than the counts for `num1`, I'd print the string.

It might look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, int> StringCounts(std::string input) {
    static const std::regex re(" *, *");
    std::map<std::string, int> counts;
    for (std::sregex_token_iterator it(input.begin(), input.end(), re, -1);
            it != std::sregex_token_iterator();
            ++it)
        counts[*it]++;
    return counts;
}

int main() {
    const std::string num1 = "A, B , C, AB, AC";
    const std::string num2 = "A, B, C , AB, A, C, AC, AB";

    auto counts1 = StringCounts(num1);
    auto counts2 = StringCounts(num2);

    for (auto pair : counts2) {
        const std::string &word = pair.first;
        if (counts2[word] > counts1[word])
            std::cout << word << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
A, AB, C,
```

If we cared about performance, we might note that we are iterating through the map a huge number of times. We could rewrite that loop in an O(n) manner, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: regex seems so strange and a bit convoluted to use in C++. At least at first sight... and at second...

Comment: a little nitpick: instead of `counts2[word]` you could use `pair.second` to avoid a second redundant lookup. At least c++17 fixes this with `for (auto [word2, count2] : counts2)`. Anyway +1.

Comment: @bolov: I could also use `std::tie` in earlier c++s.

Comment: yes, but more cumbersome